# insert into not working on oracle in date field

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, toad

I have created table as:

```
create table ot.eligible(
id number,
name varchar2(255),
join_date date,
left_date date
);
```

The problem I am getting is I am unable to insert the data which has date column:

```
insert into ot.eligible(ID,NAME,JOIN_DATE,LEFT_DATE) values(1,'ashwin',to_date(01/12/2017,'MM/DD/yyyy'),to_date(01/2/2018,'mm/dd/yyyy'));
```

before i tried without using to_Date and numeric found error was there so,I added to_date but,at this time I got error as:

```
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

My sysdate is:

```
10/17/2019 8:42:29 PM
```

when I hitted `select sysdate from dual;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing single quotes in dates -

```
insert into ot.eligible(ID,
                        NAME,
                        JOIN_DATE,
                        LEFT_DATE)
                 values(1,
                        'ashwin',
                        to_date('01/12/2017','MM/DD/yyyy'),
                        to_date('01/02/2018','mm/dd/yyyy'))
```